# Writing client-server application in global network

Tags: networking, network-programming, lan, wan

I know, how to write a C# application that works through a local network.

I mean I know, how to make my client-side application access my server-side application in a single local network.

But I wonder: How do such apps, as Skype, TeamViewer, and many other connect via global network?

I apologise, if this question is simple or obvious, but I couldn't find any information about this stuff.

Please, help me, I'll be very grateful. Any information is accepted - articles, plain info, books,
and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Question is very wide and I try to do short overview.

Following major difference between LAN (Local Area Network) and WAN (Wide Area Network):

**Network quality**:

LAN is more or less stable, WAN can be with network issues like:

1. Packet loss (you need use loss-tolerant transport like TCP or UDP with retransmits or packet loss concealment)
2. Packet jitter (interpacket intervals may differ a lot from sending part). Most common thing is packets bursts.
3. Packet reordering
4. Packet duplication

**Network connectivity**

WAN is less stable than LAN. So you need properly handle all things like:

1. Connection stale
2. Connection loss
3. Errors in the middle of the connection (if you use UDP for example)

**Addresses**:

In WAN you deal with different network equipment between client and server (or peers in case of peer-to-peer communication). You need to take in account:

1. NATs - most of the clients are behind NAT and you need to pass them through. According technics are called "NAT traversal"
2. Firewalls - may ISP has own rules what client can do or can't. So if you do something specific like custom transport protocol you may bump into ISP firewalls.
3. Routing - especially multicast and broadcast communication. In common case multicast is not possible to route. Broadcasts are never routed. So you need to avail this type of communication if you want to use WAN.

May be I forgot something. But these points are major. You can read many articles about any of them.